# Query - Comparação de Bases distintas com colunas iguais

Tags: sql, query, comparação, db2

Como ficaria uma query que faz a seleção entre duas tabelas de acordo com o valor de uma coluna específica ?

Por exemplo: Tenho duas tabelas que contém número de conta e Saldo, preciso saber quais são as contas que não estão com o saldo igual.

```
Tab1
Conta Saldo
123   100,00

Tab2
Conta Saldo
123   150,00
```

No caso preciso saber quais contas não estão com o saldo batendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependendo do SGBD que você usa, vai utilizar a função "MINUS" ou "EXCEPT".
No caso do SQL Server, sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT Conta, Saldo FROM Tab1 EXCEPT SELECT Conta, Saldo from Tab2.
```

Caso você queira também saber os registros diferentes entre as duas tabelas (número das contas que existam em uma e não em outra) você pode também fazer o seguinte:

Contas que existam na tabela 1 e não na 2:

```
Select tabela1.conta, tabela1.saldo From tabela1 Left Join Tabela2 On tabela2.conta = tabela1.conta Where tabela2.conta Is Null
```

Contas que existam na tabela 2 e não na 1:

```
Select tab2.conta, tab2.saldo From tab2 Left Join Tab1 On tab1.conta = tab2.conta Where tab1.conta Is Null
```

Comment: Isso ajuda mas com ressalvas: as tabelas precisam ser iguais ou a Tab1 não ter mais colunas do que a Tab2. E vai retornar quais registros em Tab1 tem saldo igual em Tab2, não as que faltam.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira pela pergunta ele quer saber só saldos diferentes, então não devem existir contas em apenas uma das tabelas, mas editei a resposta.